# Position divs from different table on the same level

Tags: html, html-email, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am struggling with building an email template. I would like to have one table with 2 main table data. However, the main goal is to have the green buttons, which you can see on the image below, on the same level, regardless of how long the text above them is. So for example, if the text above the left button is longer than the text above the right button, the right button should align to the left button to be on the same level in the email.

The thing is that this HTML code is for email template, so I need to use HTML 4.01 Transitional where features like flexbox doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

[image]

I tried used flexbox layout mode but due to that it's an HTML 4.01 it doesn't work. I also tried to use position absolute on the div with button and relative on the heading cell above it but it doesn't work.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="#" style="background-color:#ffffff;min-width:100%;" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="#">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">
        <tr>

          <!-- LEFT SECTION -->
          <td class="mainTD" style="width:50%;padding-right:10px" valign="top">

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="#" style="background-color:transparent;min-width:100%; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td class="#" style="padding:0px" align="center">
                  <!-- LEFT IMAGE URL HERE -->
                  <a alias="#" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="#" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="#" data-assetid="#" src="#" style="display: block; padding: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;" width="270">
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:transparent;min-width:100%" width="100%">

              <!-- LEFT HEADING HERE -->
              <tr>
                <td class="#" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px">
                  LEFT HEADING
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- LEFT TEXT HERE -->
              <tr>
                <td align="left" class="#" style="font-family:Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;padding:0px 0px 10px 0px">
                  LEFT TEXT
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>

            <!-- LEFT BUTTON STARTS HERE -->

            <div align="left" style="padding-right:0px;">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 5px 0px 20px 0px;">

                <tr>
                  <th align="center" bgcolor="#ffbcod" style="padding:13px 50px;vertical-align:middle;border-radius:5px;" valign="middle">
                    <div>
                      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" <font style="color:#292929;"><a alias="#" class="lightmode-style" href="" target="_blank">LEFT BUTTON TITLE
                            
                            </a></font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>

          <!-- RIGHT SECTION -->
          <td class="mainTD" style="width:50%;padding-left:10px" valign="top">

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="#" style="min-width:100%; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td class="#" align="center">
                
                  <!-- RIGHT IMAGE URL HERE -->
                  <a alias="#" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="#" target="_blank" title=""><img alt="#" data-assetid="#" src="#" style="display: block; padding: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;" width="270"></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="#" style="background-color:transparent;min-width:100%" width="100%">

              <!-- RIGHT HEADING HERE -->
              <tr>
                <td class="#" style="padding:10px 0px 10px 0px">
                  RIGHT HEADING
                </td>
              </tr>

              <!-- RIGHT TEXT HERE -->
              <tr>
                <td align="left" class="#" style="font-family:Arial,helvetica,sans-serif;padding:0px 0px 10px 0px">
                  TEXT 2
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- RIGHT BUTTON STARTS HERE -->
            <div align="left" style="padding-right:0px">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:5px 0px 20px 0px;">
                <tr>
                  <th align="center" bgcolor="#ffbcod" style="padding:13px 50px;vertical-align:middle;border-radius:5px" valign="middle">
                    <div>
                      <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left" <font style="color:#292929;"><a alias="#" class="lightmode-style" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="#">RIGHT BUTTON TITLE
                                        </a></font>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
          <!-- END OF SECTIONS -->
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not the doctype that prevents you from using an element. It is the email client. Use the current modern doctype.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use HTML 4.01, because it will guarantee correct display on most of email clients.

Comment: You are in quirks mode where no one ever wants to be with that doctype. It's like it's 1999 all over again.

Comment: You should use a good editor, which would show you the stray closing font tag in your markup. Note that [the font element is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font).

Comment: Why don't you just use *one*  table with two columns, i.e. four `tr` rows, each containing two `td`s? (Instead of two one-column-tables nested into one "wrapper table")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to space out your content. Change the value of 10 and 10px to the height that ends up matching the two columns call to action to be on the same line.

It will go before `<!-- LEFT BUTTON STARTS HERE -->`

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="#" style="background-color:transparent;min-width:100%" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" height="10" style="height:10px; line-height0px; font-size:0px;">
             &zwnj;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Remember to remove/reduce the space in mobile view so it doesn't look bad.